# Count matches in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

Let's have a table with five columns. Each column (`num1`, `num2`, ... `num5`) holds a unique number from 1 to 90 in ascending order. (So the lowest number is in `num1` and the highest in `num5`.) The user prompts five numbers (`val1`, `val2`, ... `val5`), which  are ordered by the program, again in ascending order, before reaching for the database.

The task is to count how many records are in the table that have five, four, three and two matches from the five number given by the user.

Counting five matches is easy, because the numbers are in the same order, so I don't have to deal with permutations.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table
WHERE num1 = val1 AND num2 = val2 AND num3 = val3 AND num4 = val4 AND num5 = val5
```

The problem is, I don't know how to start counting the four, three and two matches. 
I don't know if SQL is even capable to do such a task.

Let's deal with the four matches only for the sake of simplicity. It does not matter which four numbers match out of the five, but e.g. `num5` can match `val4` or `val5`, which makes it more complicated.

So, any hint how to solve this problem? I can restructure the table if needed, but I have to use MySQL.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design

Comment: @Strawberry How do you recommend to change the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task would be way easier if you followed First Normal Form and did not use repeating groups of columns.

Instead, create a second table, where your `num` columns are all the same column.

```
CREATE TABLE numtable (
  groupid INT NOT NULL,
  num INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (groupid, num)
);
```

You'd put up to five rows in this table for each one row in your old table. If you would use several columns to store comparable values, you really have a **multi-valued attribute** that needs to be in its own table.

Then you can query like this to find groupid's that have five matches:

```
SELECT groupid
FROM numtable
WHERE num IN (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)
GROUP BY groupid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
```

Then replace the last line to find groupid's that have three or four matches, for example:

```
...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

If you want to know how *many* groupid's have each number of matches:

```
SELECT matches, COUNT(*) AS num_matches
FROM (
    SELECT groupid, COUNT(*) AS matches
    FROM numtable
    WHERE num IN (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)
    GROUP BY groupid
    HAVING COUNT(*) IN (3,4,5)
) AS t
GROUP BY matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql evaluates Boolean expressions as 1 or 0, so you can use them like this:

```
create table tablename(num1 int, num2 int, num3 int, num4 int, num5 int);
insert into tablename(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5) values
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
(1, 5, 10, 11, 85),
(1, 17, 23, 34, 45),
(1, 2, 3, 4, 6),
(1, 2, 3, 4, 7),
(1, 20, 30, 40, 50),
(1, 22, 32, 42, 55),
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);

SET @val1 = 1;
SET @val2 = 2;
SET @val3 = 3;
SET @val4 = 4;
SET @val5 = 5;
SELECT t.matches, count(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (num1 in (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)) + 
    (num2 in (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)) + 
    (num3 in (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)) + 
    (num4 in (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)) + 
    (num5 in (@val1, @val2, @val3, @val4, @val5)) matches
  FROM tablename
) t
GROUP BY t.matches
ORDER BY t.matches DESC
```

Each row of the subquery will contain the number of matches between the column values and the 5 numbers.
So you can group by this result and count each case.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgDX7xjyYuoE4iGaBkwXQh/0).
For Mysql 8.0+ you could use a CTE:

```
SET @val1 = 1;
SET @val2 = 2;
SET @val3 = 3;
SET @val4 = 4;
SET @val5 = 5;
WITH cte as (
  SELECT @val1 val UNION ALL SELECT @val2 UNION ALL  
  SELECT @val3 UNION ALL SELECT @val4 UNION ALL SELECT @val5
)  
SELECT t.matches, count(*) counter
FROM (
  SELECT 
    (num1 in (SELECT val FROM cte)) + 
    (num2 in (SELECT val FROM cte)) + 
    (num3 in (SELECT val FROM cte)) + 
    (num4 in (SELECT val FROM cte)) + 
    (num5 in (SELECT val FROM cte)) matches
  FROM tablename 
) t
GROUP BY t.matches
ORDER BY t.matches DESC
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tgDX7xjyYuoE4iGaBkwXQh/1).
Results:

```
| matches | counter |
| ------- | ------- |
| 5       | 2       |
| 4       | 2       |
| 2       | 1       |
| 1       | 3       |
| 0       | 1       |
```

Comment: It seems to be a clean and simple solution, although, I could not figure it out myself. I will give it a try tomorrow, and let you know if it works using the real data.

Comment: @Nekomajin42 We certainly have differing definitions of 'clean and simple'!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works on my database, hence the upvote, but @Bill Karwin's answer solves the initial problem of the bad design, so that should be the accepted one.